# Should I poll on front end, or back end sending through websocket?

Tags: http, websocket, load-balancing, publish-subscribe, polling

I have a mongodb database, where I store products that can have expiry dates. I want to let the user know if a product is expired.

I don't have too much experience with websocket connections, so I'm not sure how "expensive" they are, and wondering which would worth it more.

If I poll from front end (which is n amount of users, every t time), that's n http requests, and database queries per t (assume that evenly distributed).

On the other side if I poll from back end, from a single instance, and publish to subscribers, that's 1 database queries per t, but n websocket connections loaded with heavy data at the same time, then rest for t (so n is not evenly distributed through t).

Which is more ideal?

Answer (score 1):

WebSockets are best in such scenarios. You are adding unnecessary load to the Database server by polling it + using the client's network (not a big deal but not ideal either)

Setting up WebSockets might be time-consuming and you might face difficulties in scaling it. You can use a service like [PieSocket](https://www.piesocket.com/).

Here is an example published on PieSocket about how to track MySQL database changes in real-time. Writing the same code for Mongo should be easy: [Track MySQL Database Changes With WebSockets](https://www.piesocket.com/blog/track-mysql-database-changes-with-websockets-using-piesocket/)